# Only show if there are related entries (EE 2.6)

Tags: conditionals, relationships

I have a list of related entries on a single entry page. I only want to show surrounding code if there are related entries. I know related entries has been changed recently so I'm stuck.

I would expect the following conditional to work but it doesn't.

```
{if cf_article_related}
    <aside>
      <h2>Further Reading</h2>
      <ul>
        {cf_article_related}<li><a href="{cf_article_related:url_title}"> {cf_article_related:title}</a></li>
{/cf_article_related}
      </ul>
    </aside>
{/if}
```

I'm sure it'll be something obvious but I would love to know how to do this!

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is confusing on the EL site. If you prefix the [single tags](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#single-variables) variables `count` & `total_results` with the custom field name, you will have access to control your markup with conditionals. This should work:

```
{cf_article_related}
    {if cf_article_related:count == 1}
        <aside>
        <h2>Further Reading</h2>
        <ul>
    {/if}

    <li><a href="{cf_article_related:url_title}"> {cf_article_related:title}</a></li>

    {if cf_article_related:count == cf_article_related:total_results}
        </ul>
        </aside>
    {/if}

    {if cf_article_related:no_results}NOTHING FOUND{/if}
{/cf_article_related}
```